# No BID and ASK on IBKR

Tags: interactive-brokers, iphone

While following [Interactive Brokers (IBKR Mobile) Tutorial | From Zero to Hero](https://youtu.be/v0pRujcCjXU?list=PLNtoL6rfNKdmoHyOx4ft2q9L3ue1HjE8n&t=503) on my iPhone, I noticed I don't have any numbers in the BID and ASK sections. What does that mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You took the screenshot at 8:02 pm (I'm assuming that the timezone is Eastern Time based on the timing of your post). The regular trading hours of Nasdaq is 9:30 am to 4:00 pm ET from Monday to Friday. The stock exchange has yet not commenced trading in TSLA, so there are no bid and ask prices. Check again tomorrow after 9:30 am (since your quotes are delayed, that might be after 9:45 am).

Comment: TSLA trades a decent number of shares during the pre-market (before 9:30 AM EST) and during the after market (4-8 PM).

Comment: Actually it was 8:02 AM in China when I took the screenshot

Comment: @ebepem 8:02 AM in China is 8:02 PM in New York. 8:02 PM is outside regular trading hours.

Comment: @BobBaerker Are bids and asks widely disseminated during after-hours trading?

Comment: @Flux - If it has a bid/ask price then the quote is displayed   during after-hours trading.

Comment: @ebepem Did the bid and ask prices appear during regular trading hours?